# Export leaflet map as PDF to server

Tags: leaflet

I use Leaflet to display basemaps, wms layers, multipoints, multipolygons and multilinestrings. Is there a way with JavaScript to directly, upon button click, save screenshot of map as PDF with document header and footer (image in the middle) on the server?

Today I am able to save screenshot as PDF locally on my computer with help of Leaflet plugin browser-print and print-save it as a PDF. I can then upload the file to the server and all is well. However, I want to skip this manual part of printing map as pdf, save it locally and then upload it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package works great:

https://github.com/grinat/leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter

I used it with Vue.js and make it a screenshot from WMS and Geo maps as well.

Send the data like base64image on a server and there I use https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer to create a PDF.